# Find the smallest subring of $\mathbb{R}$ containing $\frac 12$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Find the smallest subring of $\mathbb{R}$ containing $\frac 12$.
My attempt: I have formed a subring containing $\frac 12$ i.e. $\{\frac n2 | n \in \mathbb{Z}\}\cup\{(\frac 12)^{k}|k\in\mathbb{Z}, k>0\}$. How do I know if it is the smallest?
Edit: Ok, I am considering the set $\{\frac {n}{2^{k}} \mid n \in \mathbb{Z}, k\in\mathbb{N}\}$. It is a subring but how can I be sure it is the smallest?

Comment: Does your set contain $9/4$?  I don't think it does but it must be in the ring.

Comment: Consider the set $\{\frac a{2^n}\mid a\in\mathbb Z, n\in\mathbb N\}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have is not a subring. You haven't quite finished closing it up under the operations that it needs to be closed under. After you get a certain form for the elemetns of your subring, you need to argue that any subring containing $\frac{1}{2}$ must also contain all the elements you collect together in the subring you present.

Now you have the correct collection of elements, $\{\frac{n}{2^k}\}$. To prove it is the smallest subring which contains $\frac{1}{2}$, you must show every other subring $R$ containing $\frac{1}{2}$ also contains every single element of the form $\frac{n}{2^k}$. So let $n,k\in\Bbb Z$ and $\frac{1}{2}\in R$, can you prove $\frac{n}{2^k}\in R$ too? Do you see *why* this proves that $\{\frac{n}{2^k}\}$ is the smallest such subring?

Comment: True, though closer to a hint than an answer.

Comment: @GregoryGrant It is a hint, yes. I am not going to give an answer until OP has tried some more, in light of the new (to them) information that they are not done with finding the subring yet. I was hoping that simply telling In78 that their subset isn't closed under operations would inspire them to check for themselves in order to verify my claim, and then that might lead them further along.

Comment: You gave a good hint that should lead to the answer.  I just  thought the comments section above was for hints and the answer section below was for more complete answers.

Comment: @Gregory Some take it that way. I make a personal exception when the question is basic enough and calls for a pedagogical response - I try to head off other answers providing too full solutions before OP has an opportunity to retry their hand in light of new information or ideas (although this attempt more often than not fails). Ideally the comment section under my answer can then be used for a back-and-forth with the OP that guides them to the answer without necessarily doing the problem for them. Other times I do feel giving up and providing complete answers are best though.

Comment: @GregoryGrant What does "I just couldn't hang with the big boys" in your profile mean?

Comment: @Rhaldryn It means I was not good enough to get a job at a top school where the best mathematicians work.  I could have eked out an existence at some second rate school but I found a much better option - Bioinformatics.

Comment: Is ${n/2^{k}}$ the smallest subring? Can $\{n/2:n\in\mathbb Z\}$ not be the smallest? Please correct me if I am wrong? Thanks for your time in advance!!

Comment: @USER0117 $\{n/2:n\in\mathbb Z\}$ is not a ring.